# Is it legal to cut a used designer clothing found at a thrift shop and remake it into a bean bag with the original logo on it and sell it

Tags: copyright

What if made out of ruined pieces of designer clothing, a new piece of clothing like a bag and sell it. As recycled clothing. Is this a legal and viable business strategy, or would this infringe upon the copyrights and trademarks of the designer? Would there be liability associated with this business plan?Because I have access to a lot of destroyed designer clothing for an inexpensive price. And there are people who would probably like to buy a bag out of recycled/unwanted material from for example NIKE, with the nike logo on it.

Comment: What country are you in / what country will your business be in? Copyright law differs from country to country.

Comment: I'm from the netherlands. But will be working with unwanted designer clothing from all over the world.

Answer (score 1):

By the doctrine of First Sale, there isn't a copyright issue in taking a physical object that you have lawfully purchasing and transforming it into a new object. From a trademark point of view, it's not illegal to indicate that something is *made out* of material from a particular brand. But you could get trouble if your presentation of a trademark is seen as indicating that the object was *made by* the company. If Nike really wanted to go after you, they could claim that the possibility of, for instance, shoddy stitching, could be erroneously attributed to them. You would have to take care to make it clear that this is reused material.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the "first sale" doctrine only applies to computer software in the EU. There is a concept known as "exhaustion of rights" in [Directive 2008/95/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32008L0095&from=EN#d1e635-25-1) but it wouldn't seem to apply to modified goods, so Nike could probably still enforce their trademark on those goods which would allow them to prohibit the goods being sold.